# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop - date and time synchronization issue

Tags: 18.04, time, ntp, timezone

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop a couple of days back. During installation, I chose the timezone to be my local time zone i.e., Kolkata, India (Indian Standard Time). However, after booting my system, the time and date are showing incorrect values.

**Displayed values:**

date: Sun Aug 11 2019 time: 06:21:xx

**Actual values at that time:**

date: Sat Aug 10 2019 time: 19:21:xx

Precisely, the displayed time is 11 hours ahead of the actual time.

[wrong date and time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdcyz.png)

In Settings --> Date and Time, the Automatic Date and Time, and the Automatic Time Zones switches are also enabled.

[auto-update-date-and-time-enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du9hk.png)

I found some articles on the internet using which I tried to analyze/fix the issue (Screenshots attached).

1. Run `timedatectl`

   ```
                        Local time: Sun 2019-08-11 06:27:44 IST
                     Universal time: Sun 2019-08-11 00:57:44 UTC
                           RTC time: Sun 2019-08-11 00:57:44
                          Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
          System clock synchronized: yes
   systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                    RTC in local TZ: no
   ```
2. Installed `ntp`

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg -s ntp | grep Status
   Status: install ok installed
   ```
3. Run `sudo ntpq -p`

   ```
    0.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
    1.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
    2.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
    3.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
    ntp.ubuntu.com  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
   ```

   [ntpq command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFonB.png)
4. Run `sudo nmap -p123 -sU -P0 localhost`. I think it checks the status of UDP port 123.

   ```
   Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-08-11 07:09 IST
   Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
   Host is up (0.00024s latency).

   PORT    STATE SERVICE
   123/udp open  ntp

   Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.33 seconds
   ```

   [upd-port-123-status-check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w5ew.png)

What should be the next steps I need to perform to fix this issue?

Comment: Please do not post text as pictures. Copy from the terminal, and paste into the question. Please see https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format command output.

Comment: Your ntpq output indicates that you can't reach any NTP servers. The `reach` column should have a non-zero value when NTP is able to reach remote servers, and optimally it should show [377](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6812)

Comment: @vidarlo How to fix these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your BIOS clock is set to UTC+11:00 (as per RTC time in the output of `timedatectl`). Ubuntu (Unix-like system in general) by default considers the BIOS clock to be set at UTC time.

Enter BIOS while booting and set your BIOS clock to UTC time (i.e. 5.5 hours behind your local time).